# Boost Serialization of classes with private data

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Is it possible to non intrusively serialize a class with private data but with public get/set methods using the Boost serialize library.  If not, are there other libraries that are capable of doing this?
Thnaks

Comment: I think so -- http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2011/12/189177.php

Comment: Is there any example code that you know off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialise/serialise to temporary variables, if you have to (the archive doesn't magically know that the variables being serialised into are fields of the class). Adapting the serialise function from the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) to assume no direct access to data:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, gps_position & g, const unsigned int version)
{
    int degrees = g.getDegrees();
    int minutes = g.getMinutes();
    float seconds = g.getSeconds();

    ar & degrees;
    ar & minutes;
    ar & seconds;

    g.setDegrees(degrees);
    g.setMinutes(minutes);
    g.setSeconds(seconds);
}
```